# Getting Error running javac.exe compiler message, while using Ant in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

When I run my Ant build in Eclipse, I'm getting the following error message and the Ant build fails.

**Error Message**: Error running javac.exe compiler

**Line where the build stops**:

```
    <xmlbean schema="schemas"
        destfile="build/lib/schemas.jar"
        srcgendir="src"
        classpathref="xmlbeans.path"
        debug="on"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME is pointing to jdk and not JRE.
Also one thing you can do in eclipse is RightClick on buid.xml>>Run As>>External Tools Configurations>>JRE tab>>Separate JRE radio button and select JDK from dropdown>>Run button

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the same error message: **"Error running javac.exe compiler"**. The log in the output console was pointing at line 17 in the build.xml file.

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" debug="on" fork="true" destdir="${build.dir}/classes" srcdir="${basedir}/src" classpathref="axis2.classpath">
</javac>
```

I followed Rahul Yadav's second answer which is:

*Also one thing you can do in eclipse is RightClick on buid.xml>>Run As>>External Tools Configurations>>JRE tab>>Separate JRE radio button and select JDK from dropdown>>Run button*

It might not be the right answer that the user who asked this question was looking for, but I faced a similar issue and it solved my problem. So, someone might find this answer useful.